# to extract wordpress on htdocs folder

Tags: startup

i am trying to extract wordpress to htdocs folder it display a message that You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "htdocs"? what should i do now

Comment: What release/flavor of Ubuntu, what program (or command) are you trying to use extract the file (I think of wordpress as software, but you're using it as if it's a file - clarification might be handy), and where is "htdocs" located?  Is it a location your user has write permissions to?

Comment: i cant run my localhost/wordpress..i have already extracted my wordpress zip file in htdocs but it gives an error of index.php

Answer (score 0):

So I have been having this same problem. It seems to be a **permissions** problem and I found two ways to fix it. Both of assumes you are using XAMPP. If you are using LAMP just change **/opt/lampp/htdocs** to **/var/www/html**

The first I am using a **VM** on **MacOS** and I fixed it by using **'chmod'**.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

This makes it so the owner of the file can **read**, **write**, and **execute**. Everyone else can only **read** and **execute**.

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558542/give-user-permissions-to-htdocs-in-ubuntu)** is the second one I found to be helpful on stack**overflow**.

This one uses chown to change the ownership of the 'htdocs' folder by replacing the 'root' owner with your 'username'.

```
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

I ran this on ElementaryOS using Dell All-In-One Desktop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wait a minute: Your process sounds legit, nevertheless on Ubuntu we don't use `/opt/lamp/htdocs`. LAMP does install `/var/www/html`, so the user may be experiencing another kind of issue or is using another Linux OS.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using XAMPP and the poster didn't specify.